# Pigeon hole subset problem

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

For a given N numbers labeled from 1-N,
we need to pick M numbers such that there are atleast K pairs of numbers(x,y) which statisfy x+y=N+1?
can anyone help me out with this... please?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Can you figure it out for $k=1$?  What is the worst case scenario for not having any pair of numbers that add up to $N+1$?  (*further hint: think about what happens if you add two numbers smaller than $\frac{N}{2}$?*)  What about $k=2$? Can you make a conjecture based on these for larger $k$ as well?

In general and for proof, for $N$ even, try thinking in terms of modulo $\frac{N}{2}$.  Try to generalize this idea to $N$ odd as well.  (If not comfortable with wording things using modular arithmetic, simply note that each number in $1,\dots,N$ is paired with exactly one other number such that they add to $N+1$, and such a pairing is symmetric.)

Answer (score 0):

If N is even then minimum numbers required to form k pairs are int(N/2 + K)
if N is odd then  minimum numbers required to form k pairs are int(N/2 + K + 1)